# Unable to retrieve data from mysql database using netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm trying to get my output from the SQLdatabase using netbeans, the code was working flawlessly till yesterday and i made no changes to it and it isn't working now, the mysql server is up and running and i can execute sql queries form the query editor in netbeans but not from my java code. please help .

here's the code

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project1";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        Connection dbCon = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
            stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement("SELECT itemname,priceperplate from rest WHERE ItemNo=4");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT itemname,priceperplate from rest WHERE ItemNo=4");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String itemname = rs.getString("ItemName");
                String price = rs.getString("priceperplate");
                System.out.println(price);
                System.out.println(itemname);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception");}
```

Comment: Its `rs = stmt.executeQuery();`.

Comment: what error did u get ? stack trace may help

Comment: What error do you get? Please post the complete stack trace and identify the line in your code where the error originates.

Comment: How can we possibly help if you not even tell us the error you have?

Comment: Use `System.out.print(e);` not `System.out.print("Exception");` to know exception.